# Printing a page in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing

I would like to print a page in my app made up of textfields and 3 labels onto paper. The issue is I have would like to hide the "print" button when it's pressed so that it doesn't show up on paper.

Can someone show me some example code for this?

Comment: nameofbuttton.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(printPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)printPage:(id)sender
{
    // Your print command code
    // If you want to set the button visible again, you can implement completion handler callback using block implementation
    ((UIButton *)sender).hidden = YES;
}
```